# Mongo query to get documents where field doees not exists, null, empty object {}, or empty array []

Tags: mongodb

let's say I have 7 documents like this:

```
// with content.id
{
   "_id" : 1, // I know it will be ObjectId but for simplicity here I'll set it as int
   "content" : {"id" : 1, "title" : "some title"}
}
// without content.id
{
   "_id" : 2,
   "content" : {"title" : "some title"}
}
// with content.id equal to null
{
   "_id" : 3,
   "content" : {"id" : null, "title" : "some title"}
}
// with empty content object
{
   "_id" : 4,
   "content" : {}
}
// with content as an empty array
{
   "_id" : 5,
   "content" : []
}
// with content equal to null
{
   "_id" : 6,
   "content" : null
}
// without content
{
   "_id" : 7,
}
```

and I need to get all records where we do not have `content.id` in our case all the records except of record 1.

I tried with

```
collection.find({"content.id" : null});
```

and it does not return record 1 which is correct but also does not return record with id 5, where `content` is set as an empty array

also, I tried with

```
collection.find({"content.id" : {"$exists" : false}});
```

in that case, it returns the record with id 5, but does not return the record with id 3, where `content.id` exists but is set to null.

I found that the query may work with a combination of both, like this

```
collection.find({ "$or" : [{"content.id" : {"$exists" : false}} , {"content.id" : null}]});
```

but such a query works a bit slower :(

Is there a better way to cover all the cases described above??

You may ask why I want to cover both `content: {}`, and `content: []`? because PHP sometimes converts an empty array to an object, but sometimes to an empty array, so as to not have any issues I want to cover both cases.

Comment: well, I real system that id is coming from an external system so I have no control of it, but it's a good idea, Maybe I can check to get if it's not string or an empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cover all cases with `$ifNull` except `[]`. So just use `[]` as the replacement in `$ifNull` to cover case 5.

```js
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $eq: [
      {
        $ifNull: [
          "$content.id",
          []
        ]
      },
      []
    ]
  }
})
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LZH6CwG5U-x)